# Rregister a BroadcastReceiver in Titanium Appcelerator

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator

I am using Titanium Appcelerator. can anybody tell me how i can register a BroadcastReceiver to listen for Boot Events ? or if possible tell be about some good tutorial on the subject?

Comment: What do you want to do with the boot event? Run some Java? Run some JavaScript? Bring your app to the foreground? If you can add some more information to your question on what you want to do, that'll make this easier to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible using Titanium out of the box. You need to develop your own module to reach your goal.